# Unable to Select SubMenu Items from DevExpress ASPxTreeList Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

[image: SubMenu Selection.]
I am using Devexpress ASPxTreeList control in my project. When the parent node is selected all the child nodes are automatically selected bot when I try to select any Individual child Node then I am unable to display the child node since the parent is not select.

Also If try to select the parent all the child nodes are getting selected and I am unable to select or display child node.

Can any body help me...

Comment: Provide code that causing problem. Check the demos there are no such problem. creating a scenario will not make anyone to guess about your code.